# UPTADE com JSON e PHp

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estou tentando realizar um uptade com json e php, porém, fica dando erro e não sei qual é o problema. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar eu agradeço.

```js
function uptade_cat() {
    
    var valor=$("#valor").val();
    var id_cat=$("#id_cat").val();
    var nome_categoria=$("#nome_categoria").val();
 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "caixa/categoria_uptade.php",
            data: {nome_categoria:nome_categoria, valor:valor, id_cat:id_cat},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
   $('#categoria_uptade').load(); 
    $('#alert_message3').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Sucesso!</strong> Categoria Atualizado.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');

    
            },
            error: function() {
    $('#erro').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Erro!</strong> Ocorreu algum problema ao atualizar categoria.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
           
            }
        });
  }
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="cotegoria_<?php echo $mostra['id_cat'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Categoria: <?php echo $mostra['nome_categoria'] ?> (<?php echo $mostra['categoria'] ?>)</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="categoria_uptade" name="categoria_uptade">
     <div class="form-row">
      <input name="id_cat" id="id_cat" value="<?php echo $mostra['id_cat'] ?>" > 
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Nome Categoria</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_categoria" id="nome_categoria" value="<?php echo $mostra['nome_categoria'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Valor</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor" value="<?php echo $mostra['valor'] ?>">
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
        <div id="alert_message3"></div>
        <div id="erro"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="insert-data" id="insert-data" onclick="uptade_cat()">Atualizar</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**categoria_uptade.php**

```
  <?php 
    include ('../../conexao/conecta.php');


    $nome_categoria= $_POST['nome_categoria'];
    $id_cat= $_POST['id_cat'];
    $valor= $_POST['valor'];

    $stmt = $conexao->prepare("UPTADE caixa_categoria SET nome_categoria=:nome_categoria, valor=:valor WHERE id_cat=:id_cat");

    $stmt->bindparam(':nome_categoria', $nome_categoria);
    $stmt->bindparam(':valor', $valor);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
      $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
      echo json_encode($res);
    }
    else {
      $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
      echo json_encode($error);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Aparece apenas [Object][Object]

Comment: faltou o `$stmt->bindparam(':id_cat', $id_cat);`

Comment: Acrecentei o $stmt->bindparam(':id_cat', $id_cat); mesmo assim aponta [Object object]

Comment: o UPDATE estava escrito errado.

Answer (score 0):

Ja tentou enviar o post usando serialize?

ficaria assim:

```
function uptade_cat() {
    var dados = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "caixa/categoria_uptade.php",
            data: dados,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            $('#categoria_uptade').load(); 
             $('#alert_message3').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Sucesso!</strong> Categoria Atualizado.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');

            },
            error: function() {
                $('#erro').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Erro!</strong> Ocorreu algum problema ao atualizar categoria.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');

            }
        });
  }
```

No seu php:

```
<?php
$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

prepare("UPTADE caixa_categoria SET nome_categoria=:nome_categoria, valor=:valor WHERE id_cat=:id_cat"); 
$stmt->bindparam(':nome_categoria', $post['nome_categoria']); 
$stmt->bindparam(':valor', $post['valor']); 
$stmt->bindparam(':id_cat', $post['id_cat']); 
if($stmt->execute()) { 
$res="Data Inserted Successfully:"; 
echo json_encode($res); 
} else { 
$error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur."; echo json_encode($error); 
} ?>
```

Não testei mas testa ai.

Comment: Não funcionou. :/